# How to run a linux executable in multiple sessions using Python and pexpect

Tags: python, ubuntu, pexpect

I am running an Ubuntu 18 server and i have a Python script that receives a certain trigger. I want to run an executable (with a set of parameters based on the trigger) whenever trigger conditions are met. Two or more parallel executions are possible since the max execution time is 20 mins and overlaps are happening.

Let's assumme that the Python script is running and at time t1 the trigger fires. I want to execute smth like: ./executable param1 param2. The executable can stop on it's own or if i somehow send ctrl+c and then "stop". In any case i want it to stop after 20 mins max.

At time t2 the trigger fires again. I want to execute smth like: ./executable param3 param4 while the previous execution is maybe not yet completed. Again i want this to stop after 20 mins max.

At time t3 another trigger might fire. You get how the flow goes, i hope.

Is pexpect what i need? How could i approach that issue?

Thanks a lot in advance and i am sorry if the description is not clear enough.

Comment: based on your description pexpect is not necessary. python's subprocess module should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can always put the children in a list, and interact with each child as needed. Here is an example (I used 10 seconds instead of 20 minutes):

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import pexpect
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import time

print("Pexpect Children List Example:")
print("Spawning the child processes and adding them to a list...")
children = []
tod = datetime.utcnow()
start_time = datetime.utcnow()
while tod <= start_time + timedelta(seconds=10):
    child = pexpect.spawn("/bin/bash")
    # Always expect after a spawn or send
    child.expect_exact("(venv) ")
    children.append(child)
    time.sleep(2)
    tod = datetime.utcnow()

print("You spawned {0} children.".format(len(children)))

command_output = pexpect.run("/bin/bash -c 'ps aux | grep /bin/bash'")
print(command_output.decode("utf-8"))

print("Interacting with each child...")
for index, c in enumerate(children):
    command = "echo 'This is child {0}'".format(index)
    c.sendline(command)
    # Virtual environment. Expect (venv) instead of ]$
    c.expect_exact("(venv)")
    print(c.before.decode("utf-8").strip())
    c.sendline("ps")
    c.expect_exact("(venv)")
    print(c.before.decode("utf-8"))

print("Closing children...")

for index, c in enumerate(children):
    c.close()
    print("Child[{0}] closed.".format(index))

print("Script complete. Have a nice day.")
```

**Output**

```
Pexpect Children List Example:
Spawning the child processes and adding them to a list...
You spawned 5 children.
me  17004  0.3  0.1 116800  3176 pts/1    Ss+  19:47   0:00 /bin/bash
me  17039  0.2  0.1 116800  3180 pts/2    Ss+  19:47   0:00 /bin/bash
me  17074  0.3  0.1 116800  3172 pts/3    Ss+  19:47   0:00 /bin/bash
me  17118  0.7  0.1 116800  3180 pts/4    Ss+  19:48   0:00 /bin/bash
me  17152  1.0  0.1 116800  3172 pts/5    Ss+  19:48   0:00 /bin/bash
me  17187  0.0  0.0 113280  1200 pts/6    Ss+  19:48   0:00 /bin/bash -c ps aux | grep /bin/bash
me  17189  0.0  0.0 112812   948 pts/6    S+   19:48   0:00 grep /bin/bash

Interacting with each child...
echo 'This is child 0'
This is child 0
 ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
17004 pts/1    00:00:00 bash
17190 pts/1    00:00:00 ps

echo 'This is child 1'
This is child 1
 ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
17039 pts/2    00:00:00 bash
17191 pts/2    00:00:00 ps

echo 'This is child 2'
This is child 2
 ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
17074 pts/3    00:00:00 bash
17192 pts/3    00:00:00 ps

echo 'This is child 3'
This is child 3
 ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
17118 pts/4    00:00:00 bash
17193 pts/4    00:00:00 ps

echo 'This is child 4'
This is child 4
 ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
17152 pts/5    00:00:00 bash
17194 pts/5    00:00:00 ps

Closing children...
Child[0] closed.
Child[1] closed.
Child[2] closed.
Child[3] closed.
Child[4] closed.
Script complete. Have a nice day.
```

You can see that each child PID matches a PID from the parent's list.

By the way, instead of running a Python script continuously, I would consider using [cron](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto) to run the script at timed intervals to poll for triggers. However, that may not work for you.

Good luck with your code!

Comment: Thanks a lot! You have been great help!!!

Comment: YW @KTsi, but please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work